# Get-ADUser: The server has returned the following error: invalid enumeration context

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get all of the contractors and employee from our AD with enabled true for filter. AD itself is very huge and lots of data that may cause timeout limits when running powershell script. I am getting this error when I put it into variable and if I do a straight export, I am  getting timeout limit.

Is there any way to gather all of the contractor and employee data with enabled employees with big AD without having this issue? I am getting a output but not sure if the output is realiable since I am getting error.

Thank you

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,ValueFromPipeline = $false,HelpMessage = "Specify a output file name and path.")]
    [string]
    $OutputFileNamePath = $null
)
$Storage = @()
Write-Host "**********************************************************" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "*                  On Process                            *" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "**********************************************************" -ForegroundColor Green
$filter = @("CONTRACTOR", "EMPLOYEE")
$Storage = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties EmployeeNumber,Name,SamAccountName,employeeType,PasswordLastSet,LastLogonDate | Where {($_.Enabled -eq $True) -and $filter -contains $_.employeeType} | Select EmployeeNumber,Name,SamAccountName,employeeType,PasswordLastSet,LastLogonDate 
$Storage | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFileNamePath".csv" -Force
Write-Host "**********************************************************" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "*                     Done                               *" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "**********************************************************" -ForegroundColor Green
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This TechNet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32418.active-directory-troubleshooting-server-has-returned-the-following-error-invalid-enumeration-context.aspx) gives us a hint on why does this error can occur, basically:

> 1. Get-ADUser uses paging (256 object per page by default)
> 2. It is up to the client to request new Pages
> 3. When piping out AD Objects, the longer the code down the pipeline takes to process, the slower we retrieve data from Active Directory Web Services
> 4. If that slower processing causes the retrieval time to run over 30 minutes, then the Enumeration Context Expires

Most likely, your query has been running for 30 minutes which lead to this exception. Solution to this is to make a more efficient query so it completes before this time or, **not recommended by MS:**

> Increase the "MaxEnumContextExpiration" value for Active Directory Web Service. There are many reasons not to take this approach.

---

You can leverage `LDAPFilter` to increase the performance of your query, using `Where-Object` is not needed in this case:

```
$properties = 'EmployeeNumber', 'employeeType', 'PasswordLastSet', 'LastLogonDate'
$filter = '(&(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(|(employeeType=CONTRACTOR)(employeeType=EMPLOYEE)))'

Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $filter -Properties $properties
```

To translate the LDAP Filter into something readable:

- **`&`** - Logical **AND** Operator
- **`|`** - Logical **OR** Operator
- **`(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)`** - Enabled User Object
- **`(|(employeeType=CONTRACTOR)(employeeType=EMPLOYEE))`** - `employeeType` is "Contractor" **OR** "Employee"
- **`(&(...)(|(...)(...)))`** - All clauses must be met. We can read it as:
  **(** User is Enabled **)** **AND** **(** User's `employeeType` is "Contractor" **OR** "Employee" **)**

For future reference [Active Directory: LDAP Syntax Filters](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! This works for me!

Comment: @Den10102020 happy to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

I modified your script but I just grabbed all users into a `$Users` array then ran a `ForEach` loop for each individual user. Inside there is an `If` that checks that the user is enabled and that the EmployeeType is `-like` CONTRACTOR or EMPLOYEE. If they are, it adds them to the `$Storage` array, then exports it once the loop is finished.

It worked for me, but let me know if you have any questions:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,ValueFromPipeline = $false,HelpMessage = "Specify a output file name and path.")]
    [string]
    $OutputFileNamePath = $null
)
$Storage = @()
Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "-                  On Process                            -" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Green
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties EmployeeNumber,Name,SamAccountName,employeeType,PasswordLastSet,LastLogonDate 
Foreach($user in $users){
If(($User.Enabled -eq $True) -and (($User.EmployeeType -like "*CONTRACTOR*") -or (($User.EmployeeType -like  "*EMPLOYEE*")))){
    $Storage += $User  
    }

}
$Storage | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFileNamePath".csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force
Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "-                     Done                               -" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Green
```

Comment: Hi Josh! Thanks for helping but I get the same issue on my side. The LDAP solution works for me

Comment: @Den10102020 No problem! I saw the comment above, glad he was able to determine what the error was and help you get it taken care of.

Comment: He's a great connection! Most of my PowerShell issues were solved by Mr. Squarzon